# Styling label inside md-input-container with css class

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Is there a way to style the md-input label inside md-input-container using ng-class?

I am able to style it with inline css, but when a css class is applied to the label, it does not work?

Is that the expected behaviour(with any workaround?) or am I missing something?

CSS:

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
            <label class="red">Company (Disabled)</label>
            <input ng-model="user.company" disabled="">
          </md-input-container>
```

The label does not change color as it does with this code:

```
      <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
        <label style="color:red">Company (Disabled)</label>
        <input ng-model="user.company" disabled="">
      </md-input-container>
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
md-input-container label.red{
  color: red
}
```

Or:

```
.red {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared Chu! Silly of me to not try that before putting the question here. It works! :)

Comment: If it's worked please mark this answer is corrected :D

Answer (score 0):

As per the standards you should use, theme concept if you are using a material angular js. Here is the whole idea.

By default your Angular Material application will use the default theme, a theme that is pre-configured with the following palettes for intention groups:

primary - indigo
accent - pink
warn - red
background - grey (note that white is in this palette)
Configuring of the default theme is done by using the $mdThemingProvider during application configuration.

You can specify a color palette for a given color intention by calling the appropriate configuration method (theme.primaryPalette, theme.accentPalette, theme.warnPalette, theme.backgroundPalette).

Like from official site of material angular :

```js
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink', {
      'default': '400', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary intentions
      'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
      'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
      'hue-3': 'A100' // use shade A100 for the <code>md-hue-3</code> class
    })
    // If you specify less than all of the keys, it will inherit from the
    // default shades
    .accentPalette('purple', {
      'default': '200' // use shade 200 for default, and keep all other shades the same
    });
});
```

believe me you will get better lubrication in your code.
just follow :

Comment: I am already using the theming provided by angular material. However, what would help to resolve the question is if you could suggest how I can show a label in a warning color provided by the theme(color of md-warn)?

Comment: @user1242321 : you just need to do is, give a class which you have defined it in a theme configuration. Let me give you a example : 
in case of button :  
<md-button class="md-default" ng-href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</md-button>
<md-button class="md-hue-1" ng-href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</md-button>
<md-button class="md-hue-2" ng-href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</md-button>

Comment: @user1242321 : Was it useful? otherwise let me know , i will provide you another global way.

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
md-input-container label { color : red;}
```

(or)

```
md-input-container { color : red;}
```

Comment: I want to apply the class dynamically using ng-class, so I am afraid this does not work.

Comment: try this ng-class={ 'md-input-container ' : true}

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, using `ng-class` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zKLNAY)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
    <label ng-class="{red: vm.label}">Company (Disabled)</label>
    <input ng-model="user.company" disabled="">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.label = true;
});
```